# Hyperlink in HTML template of App Script not working

Tags: google-apps-script

I created an HTML template and this template is used to send email to people. There is a hyperlink that I included in the email. However, when the email is received by the recipient the hyperlink is not active. I cant figure out what is the issue here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Your Quality Audit is complete!</h2>
    <p>
    Hello <?= data[0];?>,
    </p>
    <p><strong>This email is to let you know that a Quality Audit was completed for you.</strong></p>
    <p>
    The next step is for you to click this <a href=“https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1MKlD631O5Rz2OdEPHsJMY7vNcPCvfTvP”> link </a> to view your audit results.
    </p>
    <p>If you have any questions regarding the audit, please reach out to your supervisor.</p>
    <p>Best Regards,</p>
    <p><?= data[4];?><br>Customer Support Team</p>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Below is the email received.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLnJ0.png)

I followed the html formatting that I found when I looked it up on the internet. Not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Convert this part of the code `<a href=“https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1MKlD631O5Rz2OdEPHsJMY7vNcPCvfTvP”> link </a>` to `<a href="https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1MKlD631O5Rz2OdEPHsJMY7vNcPCvfTvP"> link </a>`

Comment: Got it. The double quotes was the mistake. I deleted the double quotes and put them back and it worked. Thanks.  Could you also look into this for me. Someone had answered but I still have some issues with it. Maybe you can help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75330143/app-script-for-saving-a-sheet-as-pdf-to-a-specific-folder/75330467#75330467